# Transaction count after EXECUTE error

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have a stored procedure that looks something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure 
  @val_1 INT,
  @val_2 INT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  INSERT INTO table_1(col_1, col_2)
  VALUES (@val_1, @val_2);  

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

  DECLARE
    @ERROR_SEVERITY INT,
    @ERROR_STATE    INT,
    @ERROR_NUMBER   INT,
    @ERROR_LINE     INT,
    @ERROR_MESSAGE  NVARCHAR(4000);

  SELECT
    @ERROR_SEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @ERROR_STATE    = ERROR_STATE(),
    @ERROR_NUMBER   = ERROR_NUMBER(),
    @ERROR_LINE     = ERROR_LINE(),
    @ERROR_MESSAGE  = ERROR_MESSAGE();

  RAISERROR('Msg %d,
  Line %d,
  :%s',
    @ERROR_SEVERITY,
    @ERROR_STATE,
    @ERROR_NUMBER,
    @ERROR_LINE,
    @ERROR_MESSAGE);
END CATCH
```

When this code is executed through the database, everything runs correctly. When execute through ADO.NET I get back the following error message:

"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "`FK_table1_table2`". The conflict occurred in database "`my_database`", table "`dbo.table_1`", column '`col_1`'. Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates that a COMMIT or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement is missing. Previous count = 1, current count = 0. "

Is this happening because the `XACT_ABORT` setting is forcing a transaction from ADO.NET to be rolled back? What's the best way to go about avoiding this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check XACT_STATE() in your code and then commit or rollback, check it out here: [Use XACT_STATE() To Check For Doomed Transactions](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Use_XACT_STATE()_To_Check_For_Doomed_Transactions)

basically something like this will blow up

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION TranA
    BEGIN TRY
     DECLARE  @cond INT;
     SET @cond =  'A';
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
     PRINT 'a'
    END CATCH;
    COMMIT TRAN TranA
```

and when you check xact_state you can control it

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION TranA
    BEGIN TRY
     DECLARE  @cond INT;
     SET @cond = 'A';
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
     PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH;
    IF XACT_STATE() =0
    BEGIN
     COMMIT TRAN TranA
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
     ROLLBACK TRAN TranA
    END
```

Also take a look at these two must read links
[Implementing Error Handling with Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-II.html) and [Error Handling in SQL Server – a Background](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html).

Comment: So a better approach might be to not use XACT_ABORT in sprocs if I'm doing TRY/CATCH error handling?

Comment: XACT_ABORT is always good to use since it will clear up any junk left over and is also required when you do Distributed transaction, I will add 2 links to my answer for you to read

Answer (score 2):

IF XACT_STATE() =0    BEGIN     COMMIT TRAN TranA    END

will generate erro. XACT_STATE() = 0 means there is no transaction to commit or rollback

XACT_STATE() = 1 means there is commitable transaction

XACT_STATE() = -1 means there is uncommitable transaction which will be rollbacked by Database engine at the end of current context.